# Showing whole Company Stores Base with Sales Values in a way that allows Sales Values filtering by e.g. month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two raw data tables:

1. **Stores_base** that contains detailed informations about all company stores
   [image]
2. **Sales_transactions** that contains all registered sales transactions from all the stores that sold something:
   [image]

Now, I need to create POWER BI dashboard that will allow final user to see **whole store base** with sales values for each store ( 0 or "-" for stores without any sales). The tricky part for me, is that **there has to be possibiity to filter sales results** by slicers added to the dashboard.
So final result would look silimar to this (created in excel):
[image]

So far i only did this kind of transformations in excel, which is relativelly easy. But in Power BI i am not sure how to achive what i need.

I already have solid basics with Power Query data transformations in M Language and writing DAX measures - not very complexed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following DAX expression to achieve your goal:

```
Amount = 
VAR __sum = SUM( Sales_transactions[sales_amount] )
Return
    IF(
        NOT( ISBLANK( __sum ) ),
        __sum,
        "-" 
    )
```

The same for value:

```
Value = 
VAR __sum = SUM( Sales_transactions[sales_value] )
Return
    IF(
        NOT( ISBLANK( __sum ) ),
        __sum,
        "-" 
    )
```

This will allow you to show a "-" if there is no value and to keep your table if you select any filter.

Here are some examples:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Works, thank you :) For future generation i will just mention, that the relationship between Stores base table and Transaction table in data model is required for this to work.